# KeyError al hacer la grafica de anomalía en spyder

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pyqt, spyder

Estoy haciendo una interfaz gráfica con **qt designer** y la implemento en spyder (python 3.8) para hacer una gráfica de anomalías pero no me funciona y me sale este error.

Durante el manejo de la excepción anterior, se produjo otra excepción:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\graficando\logo_rc.py", line 27, in plot
    data["suelo"] = data[0].rolling(window=wind)\
  File "C:\Users\x1920\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2800, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\x1920\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2648, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 0
```

Este es mi código en spyder:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets
qtCreatorFile="grafica.ui"
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass= uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)
class VentanaPrincipal(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.importar.clicked.connect(self.getCSV)
        self.graficar.clicked.connect(self.plot)
    def getCSV(self):
        filePath, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', '/Windows(C:)/')
        if filePath != "":
            print ("Dirección",filePath) #Opcional imprimir la dirección del archivo
            self.df = pd.read_csv(str(filePath))
    def plot(self):
        data=pd.DataFrame(self.df['col1'])
        plt.plot(data)
        plt.show()
        estad_st="Estadisticas de datos: "+str(self.df['col1'].describe())
        wind=20
        sigma=2
        data["suelo"] = data[0].rolling(window=wind)\
            .mean() - (sigma * data[0].rolling(window=wind).std())
        data["techo"] = data[0].rolling(window=wind)\
            .mean() + (sigma * data[0].rolling(window=wind).std())
        data.plot()
        data["anomalía"] = data.apply(
            lambda row: row[0] if (row[0]<=row["suelo"] or row[0]>=row["techo"]) else 0, axis=1)
        data.plot()
        plt.ylabel('Grafico Anomalía')
        plt.show()
   
        self.resultado.setText(estad_st)
      
if __name__=="__main__":
    app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window=VentanaPrincipal()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

En el compilador se encuentra errores en def plot (self) en la parte donde esta data[suelo], no logro hacer que me funcione para que me grafique los resultados y hacer la respectiva grafica de anomalias.

En esa parte me aparece un `KeyError:0` no entiendo porque me aparece.
¿Podrían decirme cuál es mi error?

Answer (score 0):

El error es un error de `Pandas` no de Spider. Como te indican en la traza de error, dicho error se encuentra aquí

```
data["suelo"] = data[0].rolling(window=wind).mean() - (sigma * data[0].rolling(window=wind).std())
```

En concreto esta linea de código se encuentra en tu método `.plot()`

La librería `Pandas` tiene un gran [polimorfismo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polimorfismo_(inform%C3%A1tica)) con los diccionarios de Python, un `KeyError` te quiere decir que la columna que estás consultando no existe y por tanto no puede acceder a ella.

En este caso `data[0]` no existe porque no hay una columna con el nombre `[0]`.

**La solución** es ver a que quieres acceder y acceder de forma correcta:

- Si quieres acceder a una columna, pon el nombre correcto de columna
- Si quieres acceder al indice cero utiliza el método `.iloc[0]` por lo que esta parte del código **y todas las que quieras acceder a indices** quedarían así:

```
data["suelo"] = data.iloc[0].rolling(window=wind).mean() - (sigma * data.iloc[0].rolling(window=wind).std())
```